# Why The application "appname.app" cannot be opened in osx?

Tags: ios, macos, permissions

I am developing my first OS X App. after creating development ID certificate I just want to send App to my Client. I have export App and created **myApp.app**  file. After Zip, I have send it to client but when my client tried to open it,error message displayed **"The application 'Appname.app' can't be opened"**

I have tried to recreate certificate and build. I have tried to give 755 permission from terminal in client's system but still that problem exist.

I have tried almost every thing as per my knowledge but app is not working. It is really frustrating. please help me to solve this problem.

Also is there any other way to send my App. its really important.

TIA

Comment: If they have the default settings on OS X it won't allow unsigned binaries to be opened. They can right/CTRl click and select open

Comment: How can we change default setting? one more thing Xcode is not installed on client's system, Can this be an issue?

Comment: @MSwapnil, Go to  System Preference -> Security & Privacy -> General. Check allow apps downloaded from..

Comment: @K.Nimo what should I select ?"Anywhere"??

Comment: @MSwapnil, Anywhere, if the app is from unidentified developer. Only allow such apps when you are confirmed of the source.